# What is the best way for SPFX webpart development

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts

What will be the best way to organize webparts for a SPFX project.
My project is mid sized with not more than 10 webparts, should i be going on webpart per solution or or all webparts under one solution

Comment: if you do All webparts in one solution, you can keep the code tidy & reusable.

Comment: thanks @mzonerz

Answer (score 0):

Related web parts can be in one solution but keeping all we parts in one solution would cause other issues. Example change in one needs the process of removing all spfx from site etc